# Can we capture GET responses via ChromeDriver Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i navigate a page, the page makes several `GET` requests. I wonder that, can I capture individual `GET` requests by using ChromeDriver Selenium?

C# 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Selenium itself can't capture network traffic, but you could use it with this embedded [proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) and it should work fine.

Comment: nice. i wish i knew this much before :( ty

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling. :) np, glad to help